# Rails 3.0.1 and Paperclip - Image not resizing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip, resize-image

I have the following code on my model:

`has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150#" }, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml", :path => "/photo/:id/:style/:filename", :s3_headers => { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000', 'Expires' => 10.years.from_now.httpdate }`

When an image is uploaded, only the original is saved, the styles are not working.  There is no small file generated.

Comment: assuming you've got rmagick installed?

Comment: Yes, ImageMagick is installed, but perhaps it is not configured properly?  I can use it from the command line and I get no complaints from paperclip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to  update the gem to the latest and greatest

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your S3 credentials are ok, maybe you should try setting a file type for the small file. Something like :styles => { :small => "150x150#", :png }